# Javascript destructing in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, destructuring, google-chrome-console

I am trying JavaScript destructing with following code in Chrome's console tab which give me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared` exception

```
o = { a: "foo", b: 12, c: "bar" };
let { a, b } = o;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);

output:
foo
12
```

but just changing variable names, it runs fine, like following,

```
o = { p: "foo", q: 12, r: "bar" };
let { p, q } = o;
console.log(p);
console.log(q);
```

Can anyone explain me why is this happening ?

Comment: You already typed `let a` into your console or declared it somewhere on the page

Comment: maybe you have an old declaration of `a` ...?

Comment: I am trying it in new tab and haven't used anywhere else. Just writing above line in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, both work ok the first time, the problem is you executed the code more than once. The next time you'll have that error because the var is already defined when you previously executed the code.

Try the following. Open a new chrome browser and type about:blank in the URL. type

```
let a;
```

in the console twice and you'll get the same error

Comment: Hey friend, I am opening new tab and then opening console and pasted above code and it still gives error

Comment: @JaydeepKarena could be a global `a` in the page code already...try logging `a` by itself

Comment: While the code with variables `p, q, r` is working if I run them in another new tab console

Comment: maybe you're testing in a online environment, like @charlietfl said, try logging the var or build an empty html to isolate the test.

Comment: if I open new tab and then log `a` in console, it returns location object but if I do about:blank and then logs `a` in console in gives error

Comment: because maybe in the site you're testing there's already a var called "a". If you're testing in an online environment, please use more meaningfull var names just to avoid a collision with an existing one.

Comment: @PabloFerro your answer is right, but can anyone tell me where is the `a` returning location comes from ? I am just opening `google.com`

Comment: Usually in a minification or obfuscation process the variable names get transformed into another variable name. That's the case in google.com and many more sites.